# Identify tropical flower

Tags: species-identification

Can anyone identify this tropical flower? It was found on a vine(?) in a garden adjacent to a rainforest in tropical north east Australia, however it may not be indigenous.

[image]

Comment: It is a passion flower (Passiflora) Here's a similar one: http://www.kew.org/science-conservation/plants-fungi/passiflora-racemosa-red-passion-flower , but if I am not mistaken there are a lot of species.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some sort of [passionflower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passiflora) (genus Passiflora). They have very distinctive flowers.

Could possibly be Passiflora miniata.

[image]